# Complexity Algorithm Analysis with if

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, recursion, time-complexity

I have the following code. What time complexity does it have?
I have tried to write a recurrence relation for it but I can't understand when will the algorithm add 1 to n or divide n by 4.

```
void T(int n) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++);

  if (n == 1 || n == 0)
    return;
  else if (n%2 == 1)
    T(n + 1);
  else if (n%2 == 0)
    T(n / 4); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view it like this: you always divide by four only if you have odd you add 1 to *n* before division. So, you should count how many times 1 was added. If there no increments then you have log<sub>4</sub>n recursive calls. Let's assume that you always have to add 1 before division. Then can rewrite it like this:

```
void T(int n) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++);

  if (n == 1 || n == 0)
    return;
  else if (n%2 == 0)
    T(n / 4 + 1); 
}
```

But `n/4 + 1 < n/2`, and in case of recursive call `T(n/2)`, running time is `O(log(n,4))`, but base of logarithm doesn't impact running time in big-O notation because it's just like constant factor. So running time is `O(log(n))`.

EDIT:
As ALB pointed in a comment, there is cycle of length `n`. So, with accordance with master theorem running time is `Theta(n)`. You can see it in another way as sum of `n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) = 2 * n`.

Comment: By merging the two else if statements, and because `n/4 + 1 < n/2`, we could write the recurrence relation as: `T(n) = T(n/2) + n`. Solving this recurrence with the Master theorem would give the code a complexity of `Theta(n)`. Is this correct?

Comment: @ALB In master method we have to establish the following relationship `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`. In our case `a=1`, `b=2` and `f(n) = 1` because all we do, is just make recursive call, so case 2 applies - `T(n) = O(n^(log(1, 2))log(n)) = O(log(n))`.

Comment: I thought that `f(n)` is the time spent on each recursive call. So the for doesn't influence the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: @ALB, oh, i'm sorry, it's empty, i've missed it, but in most cases compiler will optimize it out anyway:) But you are right, here third part of master method applies and the answer is `Theta(n)`. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Be aware that even though your *for* loop is doing nothing, since it is not an optimized solution (see Dukeling's comment), it will be considered in your time complexity as if computing time was taken to iterate through it.

**First part**

The first section is definitely O(n).

**Second part**

Let's suppose for the sake of simplicity that half the time n will be odd and the other half time it will be even. Hence, the recursion is looping (n+1) half the time and (n/4) the other half.

**Conclusion**

For each time T(n) is called, the recursion will implicitly loop n times. Hence, The first half of the time, we will have a complexity of n * (n+1) = n^2 + n. The other half of the time, we will deal with a n * (n/4) = (1/4)n^2.

For Big O notation, we care more about the upper bound than its precise behavior. Hence, your algorithm would be bound by **O(n^2)**.

Comment: What the compiler can optimise the code into generally isn't considered in time complexity, but rather just how long the code would take with no optimisation.

Comment: You are right! I mixed concepts here. I will update accordingly.

Comment: I could see the complexity getting close to `O(n logn)` but `O(n^2)` seems too much. For the half of the time when the n is divided by 4, `T(n/4)` would run in `O(logn)` and because the for must run logn times, this should be bound by `O(n logn)`.